# "An error occurred during sign up" with no explanation whatsoever?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

Any idea what this error means? It gives no explanation. I've tried different usernames and passwords, it is not an issue of duplicate usernames or incorrect password format.

Comment: "I've tried" kinda indicates it was you...

Comment: I'm writing in first person so as not to sound clunky.

Comment: @rene The computer is a public use PC in the break area at work. It's possible other SE users were logged into it since the last clearing of cache. Also, yes, those three fields were filled in. If they weren't, the red error box would be up next to the field and be more specific.

Comment: @WakeDemons3, At first I was scared when I've seen this picture. Add a frame or something pls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix for this was deployed in the latest build.

The root cause was a bug in signing a secure request introduced as part of some work done to port old code to a new `async` code path.

Sorry it took so long to fix, there were a few other fires being put out that held up this deploy for a couple hours.